# Solr JSON Output from Array to String

Tags: json, solr

This is what happens when I execute a query via the solr ui.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1548964207972"}},
  "response":{"numFound":10,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "date":"2018-12-07T06:00:00Z",
        "Problem":["unlock a user"],
        "id":"1",
        "Solution":["solution to unlock"],
        "_version_":1624206363327463424},
      {
        "date":"2018-12-07T06:00:00Z",
        "Problem":["unlock another user"],
        "id":"2",
        "Solution":["solution 2"],
        "_version_":1624206363330609152},
      {
```

You can see that both `Problem` and `Solution` are outputting as arrays. This has caused other issues in my project. I believe this is because of how my schema is set up.

Both `Problem` and `Solution` are `text_general`, indexed, and not stored.

I believe the issue is with my solr schema because those fields in my db are only text `utf8_unicode_ci`. Below is the section for `text_general` in my schema:

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

Once my project receives the json output its supposed to count the characters in Solution so I need the output to be text.

edit: using `console.log(Solution);` on the application using solr shows that it is an array.

```
["solution 2"]0: "solution 2"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

ToWhomItMayConcern Im a new coder and am trying to structure my question to be beneficial for other beginners, if you have issues with my question or believe I could include more information or examples of what ive tried please let me know. Really trying to research enough before bringing my issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you noticed in the schema definition you have `multiValued="true"`.

Changing that to 'false' should stop your fields from being arrays.

Naturally once you change your schema you will need to reindex the data already in the search index.